# asp.net mvc 3 : how to get data in table on browser back button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, back-button

my problem is: on my layout page I have links to different dashboards. When I click on a link it displays data in table: Each link calls a action method and get a view which displays data in a html table. 
in each table, there a hyperlink field (column) which displays details about that particular record. This hyperlink calls another action method in controller. 
So when I click a link on Layout, it displays table and a hyper link in the table displays details about that particular record.
from this details page, when I click on browser back button, I need the data in the currently opened table. but I am not getting this table it is again going to Index action method.
How to get this?

help please...

Comment: providing some code might help to better understand the problem/question

Comment: HI Russ thanks for reaponse.... I can not provide you with the code ritht now but I can explain it again:

Comment: HI Russ thanks for response...I can not provide you with the code right now but I can explain it again:.I have different links on layout view to open different tables result.  I have a result table. On each row there a hyper link field. when I click on it it takes me to a view  which displays the details based on the record id.When I navigate back with browser back button, it doesn't take me to the previous result view.It takes me to the index view but not to the view from where I have been navigated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is missing some important information on your statements, so I'll have to make some assumptions!

1° - If you are using AJAX requests, the back-button won't go back to your previous action since the requests were all handled by your Javascript code.

2° - If in your posts your url don't change and you deal with values in the server side, storing it in sessions and other stuff, your back button won't work either

So basically what should be happening is one of these things. If you don't use server side sessions and don't handle requests and responses using ajax, the back button should be working, except by caching issues: http://gregorybeamer.wordpress.com/2009/12/10/asp-net-tricks-dealing-with-the-back-button/

Otherwise, if you are using ajax you should create a button to replicate the "back" behavior mannually in order to make it work, but the browser action will not work as expected.

Best regards!